# How to know the parameters for a method in javascript during development?

Tags: javascript, api, javadoc

I am java developer starting out with javascript. In java as we know, we have the java docs, method suggestions,return types and type checking for the method calls which makes it possible to know during development that I am doing the right thing. Is there a similar way in javascript? I mean how do we know that the arguments that we are passing for an API method is correct before even running the application. Is it even possible in javascript or is it a luxury that only java provides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Java, you have the JSDoc.
With a good Javascript IDE (WebStorm / VSCode etc ...) you can easily have that you want.

Comment: Webstorm helped me. Thanks.